# Loop through a dictionary to place values in a text file

Tags: python

I have a file called: "test.txt" with the following values:

```
a 0.1 
b 0.22
c 0.3
d 0.4
```

What I want to now is add a number depending on the values. Therefore I have the following dictionary:

```
dict = {
'0.22':1,
'0.33':7 
}
```

What I do now is looping through the values to see is the value is between the rowvalue and the value in the next line. If this is the value from the dictionary should be pushed. So my expected output is:

```
a 0.1 
b 0.22 1
c 0.3
d 0.4 7
```

I already have the following code which works statically. But I would like to change it so it can loop through the dictionary.

```
import os
fname = "test.txt"

import os 
path = 'C:\Users\Marc\Dropbox\PROJECTEN\Lopend\speak_distinction' 
os.chdir(path)

temp_fname = fname + ".tmp"
with open(fname, 'r') as fin, open(temp_fname, 'w') as fout:
 for line in fin:
    parts = line.split()
    #this should be dynamic
    if 0 < float(parts[1]) < 0.2:
        #this should be dynamic
        parts.append("1")
        fout.write(' '.join(parts) + '\n')
    else:
        fout.write(line)
os.remove(fname)
os.rename(temp_fname, fname)
```

Any thoughts on what adjustments I should make in my code?

Comment: I followed your example, but the explanation does not quite fit. Could you try to rephrase?

Comment: What exactly do you mean "looping through the values to see is the value is between the rowvalue and the value in the next line."? Could you explain this condition more? Is the "value in the next line" referring to the next line in the `test.txt` file? If so, when checking the first two lines `a` and `b` values, both `0.22` `0.3` are not within the interval `(0, 0.2)`, so how does this condition satisfy appending the `1` value after `0.22`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it is unadvisable to use floats (or event string that represents a float) as a `dict` key, as the same number might different representations.
Instead, I would use a list of tuples of a `(float_value, int_value)`.

```
data = [(0.22 1), (0.33, 7), ...]
```

Then sort it. It will be sorted according to the first value (float). If two tuples have the same value (highly unlikely) it would use the second, etc...

```
data = sorted(data)
```

For convenience, we will also add a minimum number:

```
data.insert(0, (float("-inf"), 0))
```

Then you can use [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/bisect.html) to find if this value is in between numbers:

```
import bisect
for line in fin:
    parts = line.split()
    number = float(parts[1])
    index = bisect.bisect_left(data, (number,))
    if index < len(data) and (data[index-1][0] < number < data[index][0]):
        parts.append(str(data[index][1]))
        parts.append("\n")
        line = ' '.join(parts)

    fout.write(line)
```

> #### bisect.bisect_left(a, x, lo=0, hi=len(a))
>
> Locate the insertion point for x in a to maintain sorted order. [...]

It basically gives us the first place in the array that is higher than our number, which is exactly what you looked for.